# Menu with different names

Tags: applescript

i´m using a Software with different Projects (Project 1, Project 2 etc.)
Is there a way to click a menu that contains "Project" and ignore all behind ?

What i try but it´s not working:

thx for help
Mike

```
tell application "Nuendo 12"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Nuendo 12"
        click menu item whose title starts with "Project" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Fenster" of menu bar 1
        
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite close.

You have to specify that you want to find the **first** menu item which matches the condition, and you have to move the `whose` condition to the end

```
tell application "Nuendo 12"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Nuendo 12"
        click (1st menu item of menu 1 of menu bar item "Fenster" of menu bar 1 whose title starts with "Project")
        
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

[@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) has already given you the appropriate syntax for what you asked, so this is merely a supplement to that in case what you're actually trying to do is to switch between the windows housing each project, if these windows happened to be called *"Project 1"*, *"Project 2"*, etc...

If this is the case, you can invoke a window's `AXRaise` action, which will  brings it in front of the other windows belonging to the same application process, and give it the focus when the application process also next receives focus:

```
tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to tell ¬
        process "Nuendo 12" to tell the first window ¬
        whose name starts with "Project" to (perform ¬
        the action named "AXRaise")

tell application "Nuendo 12" to activate
```

---

<sup>[ **Note**: `"AXRaise"` *may have a different name if you're locale doesn't fall under one of the English-language domains.* ]</sup>